# My Virgin Parse.Query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, parse-platform

I've been attempting to make my virgin query with JavaScript from a Parse database. I'd like to take data from a Parse column (named primary) and display it on the front end on a drop down.  I've tried a large number of combinations but as of now I'm unable to make much progress.  My Angular controller:

```
angular.module('startupApp')
    .controller('bizOfferCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        var primary = new Parse.Query(bizCategories);

        $scope.getPrimary = function() {
            $scope.bizCategories.relation("primary").query().find({
                success: function(list) {
                    $scope.bizCategories.primary = list;
                }
            });
        };
```

And the html (with bootstrap and SCSS) that goes along with that:

```
<div class="btn-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col col-lg-4" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" dropdown-toggle>
            {{getPrimary()}} <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
            <li ng-repeat="category in bizCategories.primary">
                <a href="#" ng-click="offer.{{category.primary}}">{{category.primary}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not providing an error callback for the query, which could be used to provide insight into why your query is failing. See [here](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#find).

You're also calling `query().find()` but you defined and bound the query to `primary` and Parse.Query is not a function, but an object. Try

```
     primary.find({ 
        success: function(list) {
            $scope.bizCategories.primary = list;
        }, error: function(error) {
            // handle error
        } 
     });
```

Also, I don't know if chaining the function call in the way you did is valid either, but I don't use Angular JS so I can't speak to the validity of this. From my perspective, it looks like you're trying to access it as a property of all of that.

Comment: thanks for the help. that worked as is. there were other reasons I couldn't get it to work do to the fact that I am a true newbie